# Transient response of a magnetron

Tags: electric-current

When the DC current pass through an inductance or capacitor, the amplitude is changing. I there is an inductance, the current will not disappear instantly, if we turn off the voltage - it will grow down for LR seconds.

Does the magnetron have similar properties? If yes, how it can be calculated? How long, after switch voltage off, there will be a current through magnetron will flow? Or it is a too complicated question?

Comment: When you say "sample properties", do you mean "similar properties"? If not, can you elaborate?

Comment: @probably_someone yes, "similar"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are asking about the operation of the magnetron inside of a microwave oven. In a microwave oven, you do not "switch voltage off" by directly switching off the 5000V power supply; Instead, you switch the voltage off by switching off the mains (120V in the US and other similar voltage in other countries). So, after you switch off the mains, the transformers, diode and capacitor hold for a very short while the high voltage supply to the magnetron. You can calculate the time from the supply current and the size of the capacitor. There are circuit schematics for reference on line. For example, this one, http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_XOzXkrse0qI/SWph08EbbQI/AAAAAAAAAEs/HRdBnvkSTUA/s1600/microwave_simple.jpg

Comment: Seems like good, and at the same time helpless answer, honestly. Well, but the scheme, You gave will be helpfull, thanks